# How do I share my Ubuntu desktop on Google Meet and Discord?

Tags: display, remote-desktop, sharing, zoom-meeting

I have a problem when I attempt to share my display in a meeting using programs like Discord and Google Meet, even when using different browsers.

Nobody can see what I'm doing on the desktop.  They can only see the mouse.

Does anyone know why this happens?  Can someone explain how to share the whole desktop?

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image: Here's a screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I have same issue on Ubuntu 22. And I have only Gnome installed. Maybe it's related to wayland somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue. One of the reasons for this issue is that there were multiple desktop environments installed into my system. In my case, I had installed **XFCE** desktop session along with the default one (i.e., **GNOME**). I simply uninstalled those unnecessary desktop environments and restart my system, the issue got resolved.